# Write a function called manipulate_data which will act as follows

Tags: python

> When given a list of integers, return a list, where the first element
>   is the count of positives numbers and the second element is the sum of
>   negative numbers.
>
> NB: Treat 0 as positive.

Why is my code bringing errors

```
def manipulate_data(data):
    if isinstance(data, (list, tuple, set)):
        return [len([n for n in data if isinstance(n, int) and n > 0]), sum(n for n in data if isinstance(n, int) and n < 0)]
```

Comment: What errors is it "bringing"?

Comment: What about the case of `n == 0`?  (`>0` and `<0` both miss it). Also -- why bother with the `isinstance()` if the stated assumption is that it is fed a list of integers? Also, note that your solution iterates over the whole list twice, which is somewhat inefficient.

Comment: your code is working fine for me, without any error. Is it not returning the expected output? Please mention the input and expected output with the question

Comment: Besides the obvious question: What is the error? what _Python_ version are you using?

Comment: The code should pass these tests

Comment: import unittest

class ManipulateDataTestCases(unittest.TestCase):
  def test_only_lists_allowed(self):
    result = manipulate_data({})
    self.assertEqual(result, 'Only lists allowed', msg='Invalid argument')

  def test_it_returns_correct_output_with_positives(self):
    result = manipulate_data([1, 2, 3, 4])
    self.assertEqual(result, [4, 0], msg='Invalid output')
    
  def test_returns_correct_ouptut_with_negatives(self):
    result = manipulate_data([1, -9, 2, 3, 4, -5]);
    self.assertEqual(result, [4, -14], msg='Invalid output')

Comment: My code gets 1 failure... test_only_lists_allowed
Failure in line 11, in test_only_lists_allowed self.assertEqual(result, 'Only lists allowed', msg='Invalid argument') AssertionError: Invalid argument

Comment: Edit your question and include the error (or anything else that might be relevant....e.g. code) instead of adding comments (hopefully that is possible).

Comment: Please find the [edit] link under your question

Answer (score 1):

NB: You should use `>= 0` if you want credit for counting 0s as positive numbers.

```
def manipulate_data(data):
    if isinstance(data, (list, tuple, set)):
        return [len([n for n in data if isinstance(n, int) and n >= 0]), sum(n for n in data if isinstance(n, int) and n < 0)]
```

Comment: It should pass this test,    import unittest class ManipulateDataTestCases(unittest.TestCase): def test_only_lists_allowed(self): result = manipulate_data({}) self.assertEqual(result, 'Only lists allowed', msg='Invalid argument') def test_it_returns_correct_output_with_positives(self): result = manipulate_data([1, 2, 3, 4]) self.assertEqual(result, [4, 0], msg='Invalid output') def test_returns_correct_ouptut_with_negatives(self): result = manipulate_data([1, -9, 2, 3, 4, -5]); self.assertEqual(result, [4, -14], msg='Invalid output')

Answer (score 1):

this should work perfectly just tried it on mine.

```
def manipulate_data(data):
    if isinstance(data, list):
        return [sum(1 for n in data if isinstance(n, int) and n >= 0), sum(n for n in data if isinstance(n, int) and n < 0)]
    else:
        return 'Only lists allowed'
```

if this works please vote up so others could be helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
def manipulate_data(data):
    if isinstance(data, (list, tuple, set)):
        return [len([s for s in data if isinstance(s, int) and s > 0]), sum(s for s in data if isinstance(s, int) and s < 0)]
    else:
        return 'Only lists allowed'
```

Comment: This should work fine but work on the rest!!